# Reallocating space for Dim-1 and dim-3 in a 4D array

Tags: arrays, c

I have allocated a 4D array in this way

```
array_4d = calloc(dim1, sizeof(array_4d[0]));
for(i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
    array_4d[i] = calloc(dim2, sizeof(array_4d[0][0]));
    for(j = 0; j < dim2; j++){
        array_4d[i][j] = calloc(dim3, sizeof(array_4d[0][0][0]));
        for(k = 0; k < dim3; k++){
            array_4d[i][j][k] = calloc(dim4, sizeof(array_4d[0][0][0][0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Dimension two and dimension four will remain a constant size but dimension one and dimension three will need to be allocated more space over time. This won't need to be done very often so I plan to increase these dimensions by only one integer.

This is the code I currently have but I don't believe I'm even on the right track:

```
array_4d = (int ****)realloc(array_4d, new_dim1 * sizeof(int ***));
for (i = dim1; i < new_dim1; i++) {
    array_4d[i] = (int ***)calloc(dim2, sizeof(int **));
    for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
        if (i < new_dim1 || j < dim2) {
            array_4d[i][j] = (int **)calloc(new_dim3, sizeof(int *));
            for (k = 0; k < new_dim3; k++) {
                if (i < new_dim1 || j < dim2 || k < new_dim3) {
                    array_4d[i][j][k] = (int *)calloc(dim4, sizeof(int));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in short, how would I allocate one additional block of space to dim-1 and dim-3? (they will be the same size)

Comment: OT: The first code example and the second code example differs in style. Why? The first has no casts and uses `sizeof` a variable. Nice and clean. The second is filled with casts and `sizeof` fixed types. Why did you completely change from a good to a bad style?

Comment: Sounds like a 4D array isn't quite suitable for whatever you are doing. Any reason why you aren't using arrays of structs etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...  but I don't believe I'm even on the right track

It seems you are on the "right track" but your solution isn't complete/correct. In short you need more calls of `realloc`.

Let's draw the data/memory structure. To keep the drawing simple let's keep the dimensions low, i.e. let's use 2 for all 4 dimentions. In that case your initial allocation code will generate this:

[image]

Now let's assume we want to increase 1st and 3rd dimension to 3. So we want this structure:

[image]

If a block of colored cells contains both green and yellow cells, you need to use `realloc` to get the new memory.

If a block of colored cells only contains yellow cells, you need to use `calloc` to get the new memory.

If a block of colored cells only contains green cells, you don't need new memory. It's already allocated initially.

The special cases are when

- the running counter for 1st dimension is greater than or equal to the old 1st dimension
- the running counter for 3rd dimension is greater than or equal to the old 3rd dimension

In code something like:

```
array_4d = realloc(array_4d, new_dim1 * sizeof(array_4d[0]));
for(i = 0; i < new_dim1; i++){
    if (i >= old_dim1) {
        array_4d[i] = calloc(dim2, sizeof(array_4d[0][0]));
    }
    for(j = 0; j < dim2; j++){
        if (i >= old_dim1) {
            array_4d[i][j] = calloc(new_dim3, sizeof(array_4d[0][0][0]));
        } else {
            array_4d[i][j] = realloc(array_4d[i][j], new_dim3 * sizeof(array_4d[0][0][0]));
        }
        for(k = 0; k < new_dim3; k++){
            if (i >= old_dim1 || k >= old_dim3) {
                array_4d[i][j][k] = calloc(dim4, sizeof(array_4d[0][0][0][0]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Important** This code is only for increasing dimensions (as requested by OP). Decreasing dimensions will require additional "special cases".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, breaking a problem up into smaller chunks can make it a lot easier to think about. Due to `C`s nature, this can cause a bit of boilerplate / repetition, but the code is much easier to reason about:

```c
// alloc helpers
int* alloc_1d(size_t dim1){
    return (int*)calloc(dim1, sizeof(int));
}
int** alloc_2d(size_t dim2, size_t dim1){
    // no need for calloc, all memory gets immediately overwritten anyways
    int** arr = (int**)malloc(dim2 * sizeof(int*));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim2; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_1d(dim1);
    } 
    return arr;
}
int*** alloc_3d(size_t dim3, size_t dim2, size_t dim1){
    int*** arr = (int***)malloc(dim3 * sizeof(int**));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim3; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_2d(dim2, dim1);
    } 
    return arr;
}
int**** alloc_4d(size_t dim4, size_t dim3, size_t dim2, size_t dim1){
    int**** arr = (int****)malloc(dim4 * sizeof(int***));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim4; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_3d(dim3, dim2, dim1);
    }
    return arr;
}

// grow helpers
int* grow_1d(
    int* arr,
    size_t dim1,
    size_t dim1_new
) {
    arr = (int*)realloc(arr, dim1_new * sizeof(int*));
    // you calloced all your arrays in your example, but realloc doesn't guarantee zeros
    // if zeroing is not needed, remove this line
    memset(arr + dim1, 0, sizeof(int)*(dim1_new - dim1));
    return arr;
}
int** grow_2d(
    int** arr,
    size_t dim2, size_t dim1,
    size_t dim2_new, size_t dim1_new
) {
    arr = (int**)realloc(arr, dim2_new * sizeof(int*));
    if (dim1 != dim1_new) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < dim2; i++) {
            arr[i] = grow_1d(arr[i], dim1, dim1_new);
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = dim2; i < dim2_new; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_1d(dim1_new);
    }
    return arr;
}
int*** grow_3d(
    int*** arr,
    size_t dim3, size_t dim2, size_t dim1,
    size_t dim3_new, size_t dim2_new, size_t dim1_new
) {
    arr = (int***)realloc(arr, dim3_new * sizeof(int**));
    if (dim2 != dim2_new || dim1 != dim1_new) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < dim3; i++) {
            arr[i] = grow_2d(arr[i], dim2, dim1, dim2_new, dim1_new);
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = dim3; i < dim3_new; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_2d(dim2_new, dim1_new);
    }
    return arr;
}
int**** grow_4d(
    int**** arr,
    size_t dim4, size_t dim3, size_t dim2, size_t dim1,
    size_t dim4_new, size_t dim3_new, size_t dim2_new, size_t dim1_new
) {
    arr = (int****)realloc(arr, dim4_new * sizeof(int***));
    if (dim3 != dim3_new || dim2 != dim2_new || dim1 != dim1_new) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < dim4; i++) {
            arr[i] = grow_3d(arr[i], dim3, dim2, dim1, dim3_new, dim2_new, dim1_new);
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = dim4; i < dim4_new; i++) {
        arr[i] = alloc_3d(dim3_new, dim2_new, dim1_new);
    }
    return arr;
}

// demo
int main() {
    int**** arr = alloc_4d(1,2,3,4);
    arr = grow_4d(arr, 1,2,3,4,  2,2,4,4);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Multidimensional arrays can be trivially allocated using *variable-length array types*. Just make a pointer to a first element of 4D array. The element itself would be 3D array. Next use `calloc()` to allocate an array of such elements.

```
int (*array_4d)[dim2][dim3][dim4] = calloc(dim1, sizeof *array_4d);
```

and that's all. Just remember to call `free(array_4d)` at the end.

Reallocation is more subtle. The first dimension can always resized with a simple `realloc()`.

```
array_4d = realloc(array_4d, new_dim1 * sizeof *array_4d);
```

The first dimension is resized. The content of an array is preserved.

However, it is not possible to change other dimensions because they are embedded into a type of `array_4d` which is `int[dim2][dim3][dim4]` and it is fixed.

To my understanding you just want to reuse the memory but not the content of the array. Therefore you can simply declare a new array type and a new variable. Next, assign it with a reallocated buffer.

```
int (*new_array4d)[new_dim2][new_dim3][new_dim4] = realloc(array_4d, new_dim1 * sizeof *new_array4d);
```

The memory will be reused but data stored in the tensor will be completely reshuffled.

Comment: Unfortunately for me the order does have to be retained.

Comment: @Goose so just replace `new_dim2` and `new_dim4` with `dim2` and `dim4`